# Unable to import LocationListener, LocationServices and Location request in android studios

Tags: java, android, google-maps, import

I am trying to get current user location in andriod studios but i am unalble to import them.

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;

import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;

import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
```

Also I have added these dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
```

Comment: add compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1' to your gradle

Comment: I have already added that dependency unfortunately didn't work.